# Generating composed operators using Table

Tags: list-manipulation, operators

Given an operator with two arguments`f[#1,#2]&` and some positive (evaluated) integer `n`, I want to generate the operator `f[...f[f[#,1],2]...,n]&`.

I tried`Composition[Sequence@@Table[f[#,i]&,{i,1,n}]]`, but `Table` does not return what I would expect when the expression used is an operator. More precisely,
`Table[f[#,i]&,{i,1,n}]`  returns `{f[#1,i]&,...,f[#1,i]}`, instead of `{f[#1,1]&,...,f[#1,n]&}`.

A solution to my original problem is thus found if given `f[#1,#2]&` and `n` I could generate
`{f[#1,1]&,...,f[#1,n]&}`.

Any help?

Comment: `Fold[f,#,Range[5]]&` ?

Comment: That's it. I feel stupid for asking now. Thanks!

Comment: `Fold` is powerful,and I am not so familiar with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Fold[f,#,Range[5]]&
```

We have given the answer to this question, here we just add another example which surprise me and indicate that `Fold`  is so powerful.

```
Fold[Sqrt[#1] + #2 &,Reverse@Range[10]]
```

$$ 1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{7+\sqrt{8+\sqrt{9+\sqrt{10}}}}}}}}}$$